# Nginx for multiple apps with different subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

Been trying to search for a time but can't seem to find a solution. I want to set multiple apps in one server via nginx. Current nginx.conf is as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.co;
    root /mydomain/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testing.mydomain.co;
    root /mydomain-test/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env test;
}
```

It serves up the correct environment (test) but doesn't serve the correct codebase. I checked the directory mydomain-test via ssh and it contains the recent code but is not being served by nginx.

Basically, what I want is:

```
mydomain.co to serve /mydomain/current/public
testing.mydomain.co to serve /mydomain/current/public
```

How is this done correctly?

Comment: I think you mean to say "testing.mydomain.co to serve **`/mydomain-test/...`**" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root directive should be in the location section. I am unsure of the rails directive and passenger_enabled directive but the rest is similar to what I use and works. Might be best to also specify the index script (i have it set to index.php but change as appropriate).

Once you have made the changes be sure to restart nginx.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.co;
    location / {
        root /mydomain/current/public;
        index  index.php;
    }
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testing.mydomain.co;
    location / {
        root /mydomain-test/current/public;
        index  index.php;
    }
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env test;
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply. It turns out the original configuration works which just need a restart.